# Проблема с проверкой работоспобности потока, проблема с .nsv

Tags: php, fopen

```
$url = 'http://83.142.226.45:32702/;stream.nsv';
if (!fopen($url, 'r')){
echo 'error';
}
else {echo 'ok';}
```

Хотя по факту,он работает и есть на сервере.
С мр3 и АСС проблем нет, если есть файл, показывает ок, нету, показывает error.

Вопрос: почему так и как проверять?)

update: По просьбам гуру пхп, убрал принудительное скрытие ошибок @.
Ошибок нет, что и требовалось доказать.
Для расширения nsv fopen всегда возвращает false.
[image: .]

Comment: Так а в чем проблема? Уберите `@`. Странно пытаться разобраться с ошибкой принудительно ее игнорируя.

Comment: Вы читали вопрос?

Comment: Да, я читал вопрос - он крайне невнятен и непонятно, в чем конкретно у вас проблема. Собственно потому не то, что ответов, а даже наводящих вопросов нет.

Comment: Вопрос предельно ясен, почему fopen возвращает всегда error для nsv,даже если он существует.

Не можете помочь или ответить, пройдите мимо.

Comment: 1. Повторю еще раз - уберите `@` и посмотрите на реально возникающую ошибку (и в вопрос ее добавьте)
2. Формулируйте вопрос так, чтобы он был понятен не только вам, но и окружающим - сильно повысите шанс на ответ

Comment: **_ясно_**! ...

Comment: Вывод ошибок включен `error_reporting(E_ALL);`?
Попробуйте заменить в url точку с запятой на `%3B`, либо при передаче в `fopen` используйте `urlencode `

Comment: urlencode делает все ссылки "не рабочими", а замена ничего не дала. К сожалению.
можно конечно в запросе выключить эти две станции из списка на проверку,но это так себе решение.

Comment: 1. Посмотрите, всё же, включено ли отображение ошибок, потому как `fopen` должен выдавать `E_WARNING ` при возникновении ошибки.
2. Посмотрите, что конкретно возвращает `fopen`. Возможно, что там не FALSE совсем, а, например 0. Маловероятно, но все же лучше исключить

Answer (score 2):

Таки да, `fopen` для указанного адреса возвращает предупреждение.

```
Warning: fopen(http://83.142.226.45:32702/;stream.nsv): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! ICY 200 OK
```

Что же значит `ICY 200 OK`.

> ICY 200 OK means that everything is okay... the user can connect there is music to broadcast etc.

Сервис возвращает код 200(ОК) и сразу закрывает соединение. Т.е. говорит: "в принципе я работаю, но вот прям сейчас поток тебе отдать не могу". Почему это происходит с конкретной станцией - это совершенно отдельная тема для исследования.